# Parse GET requests in Apache log by arguments

Tags: php, python, apache, parsing, logging

I have an extensive set of Apache logs that I'm looking to parse. Specifically, there is a PHP script that runs on the site that passes arguments to a database to filter results to the public. This script, called "searchbox.php" passes three arguments (in its URL) that I'm interested in the results for:

- engine
- query
- subengine

The rest of the information is not valuable for me at this time. Here is the format for a single log entry:

```
sub.domain.com 123.456.789.456 - - [28/Jun/2012:00:04:00 -0500] "GET /sitescripts/search-box/searchbox.php?engine=catalog-vs-worldcat&query=law+enforcement+articles&x=0&y=0&subengine=iiikw HTTP/1.1" 302 20 "http://sub.domain.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0" - 0
```

The information I need is in the GET request, I just need a clean way of pulling those three bits of information out from these large log files and dumping it into either a CSV or tab delimited file.

I imagine this will be done in PHP but I will also entertain Python as well.

Comment: have you considered using an existing parser for apache logs such as awstats?

Comment: @jordanm I don't believe AWstats will allow you to drill down to arguments passed to scripts like I'm trying to do, I could be wrong but I'm fairly sure it doesn't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regexes...

```
re_str = r"\?engine=(?P<eng>[\w-]*?)&query=(?P<query>[=\d\+\w-]*?)&subegine=(?P<sub>\w*)\s"
reg = re.compile(re_str)
for line in file:
  m = reg.search(line)
  print "Engine", m.group("eng")
  print "Query", m.group("query")
  print "Sub", m.group("sub")
```

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming you know how to read in the file line by line, you can use explode() to split the line into an array and then keep exploding the elements in the array until you get where you want to be.

```
$line_parts = explode(" ", $line_you_read_from_log);
$url = $line_parts[6];
// /sitescripts/search-box/searchbox.php?engine=catalog-vs-worldcat&query=law+enforcement+articles&x=0&y=0&subengine=iiikw
$url_parts = explode("?", $url);
$query = $url_parts[1];
// engine=catalog-vs-worldcat&query=law+enforcement+articles&x=0&y=0&subengine=iiikw
$pairs = explode("&", $query);
// and so on and so on...
```

Regular expressions would be another option, but they can get complicated and drive you insane if you look at them too long.

In bash, you could use sed and awk to parse the log.  Depends on your experience and environment.

Comment: That's a good place to start- I will have to research a bit in how to read line by line in PHP however I like your approach. Additionally, I've already tried sed and apparently the server OS is quite old and the sed documentation I can find doesn't seem to match with what is allowed on the server. :(